# MySQL: Invalid default value for TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, mysql-5.7, mysql-error-1067

I get the error

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 5459: Invalid default value for 'start_time'
```

when running the following query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `slow_log`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slow_log` (
  `start_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `query_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `lock_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `rows_sent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows_examined` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `last_insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insert_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log';
```

I am using MySQL 5.7.18

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

According to the [MySQL 5.7 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html), the following syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

What is wrong with the SQL syntax above?

Comment: Not sure if it is the problem, but do you need NOT NULL with DEFAULT? Also try removing (6).

Comment: I agree, that the NOT NULL can be the issue, because during insertion the field is initially null to get changed after the insert to the current_timestamp.

Comment: How does one end up with stuff like int(*10*) !?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interestingly, both these work:

```
`start_time` timestamp(6),
```

And:

```
`start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

You can use the latter -- leave the precision specifier out of the definition.

But the right method is:

```
`start_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
```

As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

> If a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column definition includes an explicit
>   fractional seconds precision value anywhere, the same value must be
>   used throughout the column definition. This is permitted:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>   ts TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
> );
> ```
>
> This is not permitted:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (
>   ts TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)
> );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `slow_log`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `slow_log` (
    ->   `start_time` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
    ->                                      ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
    ->   `user_host` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    ->   `query_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
    ->   `lock_time` time(6) NOT NULL,
    ->   `rows_sent` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `rows_examined` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `db` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    ->   `last_insert_id` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `insert_id` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `server_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
    ->   `sql_text` mediumtext NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=CSV DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Slow log';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is not very useful if this is in production and the table can't simply be dropped. You also didn't explain what exactly you're doing differently and why.